# My code will not write to an unprotected txt file

Tags: python

I have a piece of code for a live sub count, which works perfectly, but I wanted to then add those results to a file called 'history.txt', however when I run the code, even if I leave it for quite a while, for the loops to have looped plenty of times, my txt file stays empty.

(code is below) (i KNOW its sloppy don't judge me)

```
import requests
import time
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime

open("history.txt", "w").close()

histTx = open("history.txt", "a")

def simp():
  global histTx
  u = input("Input the URL of the channel page:\n")
  p = True
  while p:
    try:
      u.index("http")
    except ValueError:
      u = "http://" + u
    response = requests.get(u)
    r = str(response.content).lower()

    locator = r.index("subscribers")
    goBack = locator
    while not r[goBack] == "\"":
      goBack -= 1
    goBack += 1
    os.system('clear')
    print("\033[1;36;48m", r[goBack : locator].upper())
    print("---------\n")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    os.system('clear')
    histTx.write(str(r[goBack : locator].upper()))

def adv():
  global histTx
  u = input("Input the URL of the channel page (input -1 for simple mode):\n")
  if u == "-1":
    simp()
  else:
    p = True
    while p:
      try:
        u.index("http")
      except ValueError:
        u = "http://" + u
      response = requests.get(u)
      r = str(response.content).lower()

      locator = r.index("subscribers")

      goBack = locator
      while not r[goBack] == "\"":
        goBack -= 1
      goBack += 1
      os.system('clear')
      print("That channel has \033[1;36;48m" + r[goBack : locator].upper() + "\033[0mSubscribers.\n")
      print("---------\n")
      time.sleep(2.5)
      os.system('clear')
      histTx.write(str(r[goBack : locator].upper()))

adv()
```

(Before you ask, no errors, and history.txt **does** exist.)

Comment: Always close file when writing, reading or appending

Comment: Comment this line: `open("history.txt", "w").close()` and it should work just fine

Comment: Didn't work Anwarvic

Comment: First, if you want to remove everything from the file on start, you just need one open with 'w', you don't need to open it a second time with 'a'. also you don't need the `global` in the two functions. Second, are you sure that `str(r[goBack : locator].upper())` returns any output? you print it earlier in the function but then you clear the screen with `clear`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it should be `def simp(histTx)` and `def adv(histTx)`, and it should have `simp(histTx)` and `adv(histTx)` when running it.